# WPF - Hide Class name in Attached Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, attached-properties

I was looking for a way to show my Attached Properties into the Visual Studio Editor, and I found a solution [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2008/01/17/showing-attached-properties-in-the-cider-wpf-designer.aspx).

So, a property of mine looks like:

```
public class MyExtender : DependencyObject
{
    [...]

    [Category("My Options"),
    DisplayName("Item Name"),        
    AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(Path))]
    public static string GetItemName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ItemNameProperty);
    }
}
```

The property now appears in the property window of the VS editor, but in this way:

```
MyExtender.Item Name
```

Is there a a way to hide the class name in the property window, and see only

```
Item Name
```

?

Thank  you.

Comment: Why would you want that? In XAML you don't hide the class name for an attached proerty, why would you hide it in the designer?

Comment: Have you ever seen the property window in Visual Studio? If yes, you have noticed that attached properties like Grid.Row or Grid.Column just shows only Row and Column. I need/want to know the mechanism behind this behaviour.

Comment: if somehow that is possible then xaml/editor may not be able to recognize the source of the property as it does parse the written text. So you may perhaps need to tell xaml/editor everytime whether it is a property from class or it is being attached, that may be more annoying to you rather then leaving the class name as it is.

Comment: Maybe, but the Row and Column attached Properties work well without showing the extender class name. I'm asking for a SOLUTION to achieve that behaviour.